# Product of 2 irreducible representations is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, permutation-cycles

I am trying to find an example of 2 irreducible representations of the symmetric group Sn, and i want to find that the tensor product is irreducible.
My example is to find the 3 dim irreducible representation of S4 and the trivial or the parity when tensoring them we obtain an irreducible. I just want another example other than tensoring a representation with the 1 dim or itself because it seems obvious.
Any idea?

Comment: How about using a simple alternating group and the conjugation on it?

Comment: Can you help to know how to state it as a map with matrix condition

Comment: I don't know a catchy way to describe $A_n$ by matrices except as permutation matrices with sign $1$. So arbitrary permutation matrices act on them via $S_n\longrightarrow \operatorname{GL}(A_n)\, , \,\sigma \longmapsto (\alpha \longmapsto \sigma\alpha\sigma^{-1}).$ This should give an irreducible representation for $n\geq 5.$ I'm not sure about a second irreducible one.